# Does this alternator sound ok?

Tags: noise, alternator

This is a video of me spinning the alternator, via the clutch pulley, that sound recorded very softly, do turn the volume up. And if you notice an issue please let me know

https://youtu.be/Hy7hJ07wRYU

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There does sound like there is a clicking noise which is not normal.

This could be coming from the slip rings at the rear of the alternator.  Does it sound louder at the rear?  If it is the slip rings, it may be possible to open the alternator and polish the rings to remove any roughness.

There could be something loose inside that is touching the rotor, so again disassembly and a clean would sort that.

The only other thing may be a bearing, but alternators usually have plain bearings, so I would be surprised if it is coming from the bearing.  Have you tried adding a little oil to the bearings?

Comment: Hmm, ok yeah perhaps dirt or something, I was wondering more so if it might be the bearings. The car has a strong vibration at idle and I was looking at changing the clutch pulley (specting it as the problem). If somethings just rubbing perhaps it's ok. I'm hoping I can leave it where it is if it's fine.

Comment: Can you feel any play in the bearings if you move the pulley side to side, or up and down?